# MySQL: How do I select fields from multiple tables for insert to a third table?

Tags: mysql, perl

I am implementing a time tracking solution for our small company.I have this query that does an insert into a table through a Perl script. The basic query works fine but I have two inputs, `project_id` and `category_id`, that I need to use to select the id from another table for insert.

```
INSERT INTO `time_entries` (`project_id`, `user_id`, `category_id`, `start`)
 SELECT a.`project_id`, a.`user_id`, a.`category_id`, a.`start` FROM
   (SELECT
    (SELECT `id` FROM `projects` WHERE `title` = $scanin[0]) `project_id`,
  $scanin[1] `user_id`,
  (SELECT `id` FROM `categories` WHERE `barcode` = $scanin[2]) `category_id`,
   NOW() `start`) a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
   ( SELECT 1 FROM `time_entries` WHERE `project_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `projects` WHERE `title` = $scanin[0])
   AND `user_id` = $scanin[1]
   AND `category_id` = $scanin[2]
   AND `end` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

It works fine if I am selecting from one table for insert but obviously won't work with two tables. Is it even possible to do this? I am pretty good with simple SQL statements but this is complex and joins have always been a problem for me.I just don't do a lot of it.

```
time_entries    projects        categories
------------    --------        ----------
id                  id              id
project_id      title           barcode
user_id
category_id
start
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an index gave me the behavior I was looking for.

```
ALTER TABLE `time_entries` ADD UNIQUE `unique_record_index`(`project_id`,`user_id`,`category_id`,`end`)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

That is a pretty obfuscate query, with way to many unnecessary nested queries.

First lets clean it up, assuming the following database structure;

```
projects     categories     time_entries
--------     ----------     ------------
id           id             id
cat_id       title          project_id
usr_id                      user_id
title                       user_id
                            category_id
                            start
                            end
```

We can simplify your query to a more developer friendly version;

```
INSERT INTO `time_entries` (`project_id`, `user_id`, `category_id`, `start`)

SELECT project_id, user_id, category_id, now()
FROM projects JOIN category ON projects.cat_id = category.id
WHERE project_id NOT IN (
          SELECT project_id
          FROM time_entries
          WHERE title = $scanin[0]
             AND `user_id` = $scanin[1]
             AND `category_id` = $scanin[2]
             AND `end` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
         )
```

Ok, so now it should be much easier to add another table as you requested by using the following pattern;

```
INSERT INTO time_e... ,  column_n, column_n_plus_1
....
FROM proj....
      JOIN table_n on id_n = project_id
      JOIN table_n_plus_one on id_n_plus_one = project_id
....
```

Comment: I will spend some time with this over the weekend and see if I can make it work. I added the correct table structure to my op. Thank you.